# Basketball probability

Tags: probability

Three basketball teams enter a league. If Team A is twice as likely to win as Team B, and Team B is five times as likely to win as Team C, what is the probability of Team C winning?

I let the probability of Team C winning be $\frac{1}{x}$, then the probability of Teams A and B winning would be $\frac{10}{x}$ and $\frac{5}{x}$ respectively. Furthermore, they should sum up to $1$ then $x=16$. So the probability of Team C winning is $\frac{1}{16}$. Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your working is correct.

Further underlying assumptions that are not stated explicitly are there are just these $3$ teams or only these $3$ teams can win the tournament.